# mb_stripos not working with accented characters

Tags: php

I'm trying to make `mb_stripos` to work with accented characters but I can't find any way to do it.

```
$word = "leilao";
$text = "LeiLao LEilões lllleeil";
$result = mb_stripos($text, $word);
//works

$word = "leilão";
$text = "LeiLão LEilões lllleeil";
$result = mb_stripos($text, $word);
//doesn't works
```

I checked `mb_internal_encoding()` and is set to `utf-8`

Can someone help me?

What I need is to search in a long text if an array of keywords exists and just return true. But I need the accented character to be found aswell.

There is another way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

**[UPDATE]**

I found where is the problem.
I'm trying to get some text from the database,and it is all set to utf8.

```
//after the query I assign like this:
$text = $rows[0]["description"];
```

If I use `mb_detect_encoding` I get as result `ASCII` encoding.
And there is no function to change that!
I tried it all, `iconv`, `mb_convert_encode`, `utf8_encode`, but the result is always `ASCII`.
And I need to match accented characters/words but the result is always 0.

Comment: Are you sure that your source code file is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: @Sven actually I'm not sure anymore, I tried using `mb_detect_encoding` and is returning ASCII instead of UTF-8

Comment: You have to get at the bytes that are representing the characters you see. You can abuse the `urlencode()` function for this - it will convert all more special characters that are not allows in a URL into percent-hex representation. This will help you identify what bytes are in your string, and you might find out which encoding you really have. Note that autodetecting encoding is impossible to code right, it is always a guess, because all you have are bytes - and depending on encoding they mean different things.

Comment: @Sven it was a good idea, but still not working.. for example in the text I have the word `única` and if I use `$text_encoded = urlencode($text)` the word is encoded to `%26uacute%3Bnica` and the `$word = "única"` is encoded to `%C3%BAnica`

Comment: `%26` is the ampersand &, "uacute" is the entity name for the "ú", and %3B is the semicolon. This means that in your `$text` there is an `htmlentities()` version of the string, NOT unicode. So if $text comes from a database, this database does not contain UTF-8, but was filled with html entities. You have to investigate where the data comes from, and see why it sends you entities - or whether you convert the strings into entities.